# Please explain work done

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, definition, displacement

We have learnt that when an force displaces object along its direction then it is work done. so there is dot product in its formula (I guess). So is it also right to say that work done is cross product of displacement and force if we consider the  perpendicular component of force regardless the typical definition of work?

Answer (score 0):

Work is the dot product of Force and displacement not cross product.If you consider the perpendicular component of force work done by the perpendicular component is zero . I think you should read the definition of work done.As work is a dot product it's a scalar quantity not a vector. So W=F.S or W=Fscosθ .Now if you consider the perpendicular component θ=90° and So cosθ=0 and therefore work done is zero along that direction

Answer (score 0):

In layman's terms , Work Done can be defined as the product of the Force(that is causing the displacement) times the amount of displacement.

When we write $W = \vec{F}.d\vec{s}$   , what we actually mean is that the Work is done by the Force that causes the **Displacement** only. And that force would be the component of the $\vec{F}$ that is along the $d\vec{s}$ vector.

Take this example:

[image: pic1]

Here , the Component of $\vec{F}$ perpendicular to the $d\vec{s}$ is playing no role in displacing the body. Hence **this component has no role doing any work on the object**.

Now , moving on to your second question: "Why isn't Work Done a vector ?"

Well , it isn't because of definition. A vector is any quantity that  captures the essence of its orientation along with its magnitude. In vectors ,the signs  $+$ and $-$ are just a mere indication of its direction in a plane.

However in scalars , $+$ and $-$ actually denotes whether there is a loss or gain of any form.

Work Done is similar. Its direction has nothing to do in determining where an object will move. If I ask you which direction would a body move if I apply 20J of work on it, you wont be able to answer.

But if I rephrase it as if I apply a force of $20N i $, you will be able to answer.